# rake routes--> rake aborted! syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (Mac)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rubygems, rake

Hello i'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I was trying to set up a blog. 
I ran "rake routes" and I got the error copy and pasted below.
I would greatly appreciate help fixing it (have not found anything similar online.)

dhcp-18-111-5-233:blog ronaldoisabeast$ rake routes
rake aborted!
/Users/ronaldoisabeast/Desktop/Rails/blog/config/routes.rb:58: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
/Users/ronaldoisabeast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/ronaldoisabeast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in`block in load'
/Users/ronaldoisabeast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/Users/ronaldoisabeast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in`load'
/Users/ronaldoisabeast/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
paths'

Comment: what does your config/routes.rb file look like.

Answer (score 0):

There is some end missing in your config/routes.rb if you can put it here we will be able to find the bug